# multivariate regression model using aggregated data (both outcome and independent variables are reported as mean and standard deviation)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, standard-deviation, mean

I have a dataset where my main variable of interest and my six outcomes are reported as mean and sd (aggregated data). Basically for each of the individuals in the dataset (N=300), the measure is reported in this way.

Controlling for additional covariates I would like to assess the association between 1) the variable of interest and each of the six outcomes 2) the variable of interest and all six outcomes together (multivariate linear regression model).

If I had to use only the mean (as reported), I wouldn't have problems in analysing the data. However, by omitting to consider the SD in the analysis it feels like I am omitting a very important part of the analysis. How to address this issue?

Thanks in advance.